# How to search for log4j vulnerability?

Tags: security, log4j

What will be the best way to search for log4j vulnerability? Is it a search for "log4j" keyword in the source code enough? Does it only affects Java applications? I read somewhere that applications sometimes rename log4j under another name. A quick google search gives several tools than claim can detect the vulnerability.

Comment: You need to look for a file matching the pattern 'log4j-core-*.jar'. If you find this jar in your deployed application, you may be vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

The vulnerability comes from `JndiLookup.class`. In your console use the following command:

`sudo grep -r --include "*.jar" JndiLookup.class /`

If it returns nothing, you are not vulnerable.
But you may encounter such returns:

`Fichier binaire /home/myuser/docx2tex/calabash/distro/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar correspondant`

or

`grep: /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.jar : fichiers binaires correspondent`

The first one is clearly vulnerable (version matches), the second one has to be investigated. To mitigate the risk I've immediately removed the JndiLookup.class with the following:

`zip -q -d log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`

and

`zip -q -d arara.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`

Applications may continue to work, or not. By the way upgrading to versions using log4J >= 2.17 has to be done. This is the next step, in the meantime you are no more vulnerable.

Comment: Are these log4j vulnerabilities only for web (tomcat or jboss deployment) or also for standalone use of log4j.jar, are there any clarifications written anywhere :
   
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228  
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046  
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4104  
 
for standalone to be vulnerable you’d have to configure not just plain logging to file, but logging to socket console with socket appender ?, 
thank you for any clues.

Comment: I've applyed this to servers and desktops for web and standalone use of log4j.jar. I've been surprised to discover such library where I was not expecting it. All occurrences will be upgraded asap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below scanner to identify vulnerable log4j jar files in your application.
https://github.com/logpresso/CVE-2021-44228-Scanner

I have used jar version to scan the application.
Download jar from from:
https://github.com/logpresso/CVE-2021-44228-Scanner/releases/download/v2.4.2/logpresso-log4j2-scan-2.4.2.jar

Open a command prompt in the same location and execute the below command to scan your application

```
java -jar logpresso-log4j2-scan-2.4.2.jar 'your application path'
```

[image]